# MySQL REGEXP not working

Tags: mysql, regex, concatenation

I am trying to update my product database and find duplicates after some product numbers were simplified.

Here is what I am trying that is not working:

```
SELECT b.Id as OLDID, c.Id as NEWID
FROM productdata b, productdata c
WHERE b.ProdNum REGEXP CONCAT('^', c.ProdNum, '(\-|\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\-|\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+')
```

Old Product number: WR-101 3 Day (as well as WR-101 1 Day, etc.)

New Product number: WR-101

So basically I need a where clause that will match up the new Product number with the old product number that had "1 Day", "3 Day" etc. on them.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know the REGEX is more complex than it needs to be, but I ok with the extra resources and I want one that can catch more than this specific problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL's regex flavor does not support `\s` for spaces.  You need to use `[[:space:]]`.  You also don't need to escape the dash:

```
(-|[[:space:]])[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-|[[:space:]])[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Comment: +1 You can further simplify with `[-[:space:]]` instead of `(-|[[:space:]])`